# Can I see my TFL travel history when I've used contactless?

Tags: public-transport, london, tfl, oyster-card, contactless

On a visit to London I used a contactless credit card to tap in and out of public transport.

I know that can look up travel history online for Oyster cards, having done so in the past, but can it be done for contactless? Online search suggests it can done through the "TFL oyster and contactless" app (but are sketchy on the details). However said app will do nothing until I've created an account, and the account creation process requires me to enter "my UK address", which I don't have.

In fact, not being a UK resident is my main reason for going contactless, as that avoids having a leftover balance sitting on an Oyster for ages.

Is there another way? One that a non-resident can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the travel and payment history of the past seven days, you may consult the records without registration: https://contactless.tfl.gov.uk/UnregisteredCustomer/Show.

Otherwise, you can create a TfL account and register  your card there: https://accounts.tfl.gov.uk/Register. There is no requirement for a UK address, at least when registering on the website.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for (first link). Odd that the search results were all about an app, and not this fine online option.

Comment: I was also able to register an account (second link). There was a puzzling "address line 4" that was mandatory (line 2 & 3 weren't), but no problem (I put in my city). Answer marked as accepted, as it cannot be more complete.

Comment: Important - if you have an account and register a card, TFL won't show any journeys before the card was registered. If you then try to check the last 7 days as an unregistered customer, your request will be declined with reason the card is already registered and to login to view history. 
I then tried to remove the card from my account but the 7 day history still shows as empty for one journey 7 days before